# Count cumulative/increase for each id [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sum, cumulative-sum

I would like to count an increase values for each record from this below table (table_values):

```
  id | open | closed | in_progress | project |
  1  | 0    | 0      | 0           | 20      | 
  2  | 1    | 0      | 1           | 20      |
  3  | 1    | 1      | 1           | 55      | 
  4  | 1    | 1      | 1           | 20      | 
  5  | 1    | 1      | 1           | 20      | 
  6  | 2    | 2      | 0           | 20      |
```

So for example to select where project = 20
results should be:

```
 id | open | closed | in_progress | project | Total |
 1  | 0    | 0      | 0           | 20      |  0    |
 2  | 1    | 0      | 1           | 20      |  2    |
 4  | 2    | 1      | 2           | 20      |  3    |
 5  | 3    | 2      | 3           | 20      |  3    |
 6  | 5    | 4      | 3           | 20      |  4    |
```

Select should return cumulative results for each id if possible.
Any suggestions?

Regards.

UPDATE:
TABLE:

```
  id | open | 
  1  | 2    |
  2  | 3    |
  3  | 5    |
```

Result:

```
  id | open | cumulative_open
  1  | 2    | 2
  2  | 3    | 5
  3  | 5    | 10
```

Comment: little information for analysis

Comment: My suggestion is that tell us why you want to do this, on what kind of platform, and preferably what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses parameters and looks to achieve what you have described.  You might want to amend the names, though, as some are probably a bit unsuitable (as they're closed to reserved names)

```
SET @open = 0;
SET @closed = 0;
SET @in_progress = 0;
select 
id,
(@open := @open + open) as open,
(@closed := @closed + closed) as closed,
(@in_progress := @in_progress + in_progress) as in_progress,
project,
(open + closed + in_progress) as Total
FROM table_values
where project = 20
group by id;
```

Comment: note: this pattern with user defined variables depends on behavior which is not guaranteed. From the MySQL Reference Manual:  "As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.... you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed." Reference:   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: I don't see this as a vulnerability in this instance.  The variable isn't being "selected" outside of the operation in which it is set, so there is no ordering issue.

Comment: Why are you using `group by` and `sum`?

Comment: end of day syndrome.  I've edited, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can join the rows with all previous (including the same) rows from the same project and use `SUM()`:

```
select t1.id,
    sum(t2.open) as open,
    sum(t2.closed) as closed,
    sum(t2.in_progress) as in_progress,
    t1.project,
    t1.open + t1.closed + t1.in_progress as Total
from table_values t1
join table_values t2
  on  t2.project = t1.project
  and t2.id <= t1.id
where t1.project = 20
group by t1.id
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/NZDN42998

This is an expensive query (in terms of performance) - But at least it's reliable.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING :)